# Adding custom block to catalog product view

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, module, xml, custom-block

I'm currently making my own module, but i'm having trouble with just displaying a block in the catalog product view.

I've added this line to default/layout/catalog.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.rating" template="rating/rating.phtml"/>
```

and my template/rating/rating.phtml looks like this

```
<p>halp</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your `your_theme_path/layout/local.xml` instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="product.info">
       <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.rating" template="rating/rating.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Now call child html in `theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.info.rating') ?>
```

**Another way**

If you don't want to edit `theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file then change your `local.xml` as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="alert.urls">
       <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.rating" template="rating/rating.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

This block will appear automatically in product view page, however it will be called along with other `alert.urls`

Comment: I figured it out, it was because the view.phtml was in another theme.

But thanks for your help

Comment: Great, you still can choose this as right answer to help others. Cheers